# Revit API - How to read correct BuiltInParameter values from a list of FamilyParameter

Tags: c#, autodesk, revit-api, revit

I'm trying to read `BuiltInParameter, Parameter Name, Parameter Type` etc from a list of `FamilyParameter` instance. The code I'm using to read the FamilyParameter is written here on the [**GitHub**](https://gist.github.com/imAliAsad/198a6cac035f9474456390d0aba10a9c#file-readrevitfamily-cs). The output of the code is [**here**](https://gist.github.com/imAliAsad/198a6cac035f9474456390d0aba10a9c#gistcomment-2336115).  As you can see, there are a lot of **INVALID** values in BuiltInParameter Column.  But when I cross check the value of BuiltInParameter, it is not INVALID.

I'm wondering if someone could explain, how could I get the valid BuiltInParameter data from the list FamilyParameter. Appreciate any help. Thank you.

[Original Source](https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/revit-api-forum/how-to-read-correct-builtinparameter-values-from-a-list-of/td-p/7735066)

Comment: You mention that when you cross check the value of BuiltInParameter (BIP) it does not show as INVALID, at what point are you performing this check?  Because from my experience working with the Revit API, what you are getting makes sense.  

Check the value of the BuiltInParameter object you're performing the ToString() on at this line  - 

`BuiltinParameter = ((InternalDefinition)familyparam.Definition).BuiltInParameter.ToString()`

I am willing to bet that will be coming in as INVALID.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably take a look at [BipChecker, the built-in parameter checker](https://github.com/jeremytammik/BipChecker). Looking at the output you are generating, it probably already does all you require.